# Control which border position sets the corner pixels in CSS

Tags: css

Imagine the following CSS:

```
#foo {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

In this case, at least under Chrome, the top and bottom right corner pixels of the element are blue, not black. Is it possible to make them black?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with the normal CSS border options, but if you want to, you can still have a pure CSS solution:
Basically, what you are going to do is create two pseudo elements with CSS, and cover the corners:

```
#foo {
    border: 100px solid black;
    border-right: 100px solid blue;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
#foo:after, #foo:before{
    content:'';
    background:black;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
#foo:after{
    bottom:-100px;
    right:-100px;
}
#foo:before{
   top:-100px;
    right:-100px;
}
```

It might be a little messy, but it works. Set the `:after` and `:before` elements width height and position to the width of the border.
And that gives this effect:
[image: result]

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/3nkgwtcr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I hope my crappy photoshop skills explain borders to you.

If you look in the 4 corners of the square you can see little lines, thats where one border starts and the next one begins.

This will always be in issue :P

You could either make it a background image (crappy way)

or you can use other divs to make the borders (crappy as well)

Answer (score 1):

The first solution would be using a pseudo-element, which you will position absolutely to cover the right border. In order to ensure that it covers the border entirely, you will have to offset its top, bottom and right positions by the negative value of the border width. In this case I have used a width of `5px` to better illustrate the example:

```css
#foo {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 5px solid grey;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
#foo::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -5px; /* move by border width */
    background-color: blue;
    width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can use CSS box shadow:

```css
#foo {
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px grey;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
#foo::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your problem is how borders are drawn in CSS.

`<div id="foo">Problem</div>`

```
#foo {
  border: 30px solid black;
  border-right: 30px solid blue;
}
```

[image]

The simplest way to work around this is to use a [pseudo element](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/). Since this workaround is entirely dependent on the value of the `border-width`, I’ll show an example using an [SCSS](http://alistapart.com/article/getting-started-with-sass) variable to help make it clear where that width value is coming in.

*Note: You don’t need SCSS to solve this problem, using a variable just helps readability/maintainability.*

HTML:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

SCSS:

```
/* Set SCSS variable */
$border-width: 30px;

#foo {
  border: $border-width solid black;
  position: relative; /* anchor the absolute positioned ::after element */
}
#foo:after {
  content: '';
  background: blue;
  width: $border-width;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -$border-width;
}
```

**Demo:** [http://jsbin.com/cimaxe/6](http://jsbin.com/cimaxe/6/edit?html,css,output)

Hopefully it’s clear that everywhere you see `$border-width` you can replace it with a value like `30px`.

[image]